# undefined method 'map' for nil class

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid, production

I'm a newbie and I got some trouble when run rails 3 server with mongodb (using mongoid) in production mode. Everything is ok in development mode, and I cannot figure out what am I missing. Please help me, thank you very much. This is the error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass):

```
2: #control{:style => "float: left;"}
3:   %h3= t(:manage_shop)
4:   =# debugger
=###### Already checking @shops variable but still got error ######
5:   = hidden_field_tag :shop_list, @shops.blank? ? "test" : @shops.to_json
6:   = form_tag("/shop", :method => "POST", :id => "frm_create_shop") do
7:     %table
8:       %tr
```

> app/views/shop/index.html.haml:5:in`_app_views_shop_index_html_haml___1855911541554609468_28040500'

this is my action:

```
def index
  @shops = Shop.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

my model:

```
class Shop
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Geospatial

  field :id,          type: Integer
  field :name,        type: String
  field :position,    type: Point, :spatial => true, :delegate => true

  spatial_scope :position
end
```

and my production.rb configuration:

```
Trunk::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

And the second thing is I cannot get anything from db although everything is work well in development mode. If you have any suggestion, please help, thanks.

Comment: Can you post your production mongoid.yml? (Please remove any sensitive data)